# Rich snippets preview tool is removed?

Tags: seo, markup, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

Is there any way to preview how my structured data will actually look on Google? The [markup helper](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/) only gives the HTML code, but I don't see anywhere that gives a preview of what it would look on Google Search.

Am I missing something or they did removed the preview tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version of the Google Structured Data Testing Tool was https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets. It showed search result snippet previews.

This now redirects to the second version of the tool: https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/. It no longer shows the snippet previews.

If the new tool detects structured data that Google makes use of, you can click on <kbd>Filter by use case</kbd> and select a use case, which shows the link <kbd>(what's this?)</kbd> where you can get more information about it. This page typically displays an example snippet (but of course only with general data, not your specific example).